# How to check if string is a valid class identifier?

Tags: java, class

Is there some nice way to check that some string represents a valid (fully qualified) Java class name? For example `org.comPAny.ClassName` or even `mYcRAZYcLASSnAME` are valid class names but something like `org..package.MyClass` or `org.ClassName.` are not. I want to check class name validity without loading that class.

Is there some convenient method in Java to check that? Or can you provide regular expression that is granted to cover all cases?

EDIT: Please do not suggest third party libraries.

Comment: Regex: /^(\w+\.)*[\w]+$/, looks like that can do it (very poor and cheap by the way).

Comment: Luiggi this also captures: 1java.lang.String which is not correct

Answer (score 12):

If you really want a bullet-proof solution, split the string by `"\\."` and use first

```
Character.isJavaIdentifierStart
```

and the in a loop

```
Character.isJavaIdentifierPart
```

to check that the parts are valid identifier names.

**Edit:** `#split(String)` interprets the string as regex, so make sure you split the String by `"\\."` rather than just `"."` as you'd expect by the principle of least surprise. What a bad API design, yikes! That's what you get from not having regex literals in your language…

Comment: You can't split by dot `.`, which will consume every other character. Instead, split by `(?<=.)` - a non-consuming look behind

Comment: @Bohemian Can you explain the problem with splitting by `\\.` in more detail, please? What is the difference in your suggestion?

Comment: @drasto Actually, it's worse that that: splitting on dot consumes *everything*, ie `"abcde".split(".")` produces an empty array `[]`

Comment: Gotcha, split interprets the string as regex. What a bad API design, yikes!

Comment: @Bohemian that is because `.` matches any character. It has to be escaped first in order to really match only dots. This matches only dots and does not consume anything: `\\.`

Comment: @drasto you are correct that `"\\."` splits on literal dots, but it's untrue that it "doesn't consume anything"; it consumes the dots. That's why splitting on `"."` consumes *everything*, leaving an empty array - all characters are consumed as separators and `split()` throws away empty strings

Comment: @akuhn it's not a bad API design - the parameter of `split()` is named `regex` - it's pretty obvious

Comment: @Bohemian it is bad design, in a typed language I expect parameters to be treated as their type suggests. String is a String is a String and Pattern is a Pattern is a Pattern.

Answer (score 9):

The *proper* way to do this is to use [javax.lang.model.SourceVersion.isName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html#isName-java.lang.CharSequence-) method (part of Java standard library).

Answer (score 3):

```
public static boolean isValidJavaIdentifier(String s)
{
 // an empty or null string cannot be a valid identifier
 if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
 {
    return false;
 }

 char[] c = s.toCharArray();
 if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c[0]))
 {
    return false;
 }

 for (int i = 1; i < c.length; i++)
 {
    if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c[i]))
    {
       return false;
    }
 }

 return true;
}
```

Reference:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/CheckwhetherthegivenStringisavalididentifieraccordingtotheJavaLanguagespecifications.htm

Comment: This only checks simple class name (without package) but not the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 3):

Different versions of the Java platform support different Unicode versions.

So different versions will support different *valid* identifiers.

The following accounts for identifiers outside the BMP, and Java reserved words.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public enum PackageName {

  SIMPLE, QUALIFIED, INVALID;

    public static final PackageName check(String name) {
    PackageName ret = PackageName.INVALID;
    int[] codePoint;
    int index = 0, dotex = -1;
    boolean needStart = true;
    escape: {
      if(name == null || name.isEmpty()) break escape;
      if(name.codePointAt(0) == '.') break escape;
      codePoint = name.codePoints().toArray();
      while (index <= codePoint.length) {
        if(index == codePoint.length) {
          if(codePoint[index - 1] == '.'){
            ret = PackageName.INVALID; break escape;}
          int start = dotex + 1;
          int end = index;
          start = name.offsetByCodePoints(0, start);
          end = name.offsetByCodePoints(0, end);
          String test = name.substring(start, end);
          if(!(Arrays.binarySearch(reserved, test) < 0)){
            ret = PackageName.INVALID; break escape;}
          if(!(ret == PackageName.QUALIFIED)) ret = PackageName.SIMPLE;
          break escape;
        }
        if(codePoint[index] == '.') {
          if(codePoint[index - 1] == '.'){
            ret = PackageName.INVALID;  break escape;}
          else {
            needStart = true;
            int start = dotex + 1;
            int end = index;
            start = name.offsetByCodePoints(0, start);
            end = name.offsetByCodePoints(0, end);
            String test = name.substring(start, end);
            if(!(Arrays.binarySearch(reserved, test) < 0)) break escape;
            dotex = index;
            ret = PackageName.QUALIFIED;
          }
        } else if(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(codePoint[index])) {
          if(needStart) needStart = false;
        } else if((!Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(codePoint[index]))){
          ret = PackageName.INVALID; break escape;
        } 
        index++;
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }

  private static final String[] reserved;

  static {
    reserved = new String[] { "abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break", "byte",
        "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const", "continue", "default", "do",
        "double", "else", "enum", "extends", "false", "final", "finally",
        "float", "for", "if", "goto", "implements", "import", "instanceof",
        "int", "interface", "long", "native", "new", "null", "package",
        "private", "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static",
        "strictfp", "super", "switch", "synchronized", "this", "throw",
        "throws", "transient", "true", "try", "void", "volatile", "while" };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nice solution for your problem:

```
public static boolean isFullyQualifiedClassname( String classname ) {
      if (classname == null) return false;
      String[] parts = classname.split("[\\.]");
      if (parts.length == 0) return false;
      for (String part : parts) {
          CharacterIterator iter = new StringCharacterIterator(part);
          // Check first character (there should at least be one character for each part) ...
          char c = iter.first();
          if (c == CharacterIterator.DONE) return false;
          if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c) && !Character.isIdentifierIgnorable(c)) return false;
          c = iter.next();
          // Check the remaining characters, if there are any ...
          while (c != CharacterIterator.DONE) {
              if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c) && !Character.isIdentifierIgnorable(c)) return false;
              c = iter.next();
          }
      }
      return true;
  }
```

Source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/DeterminewhetherthesuppliedstringrepresentsawellformedfullyqualifiedJavaclassname.htm

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this ?

http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/classscan/apidocs/org/apache/commons/classscan/builtin/ClassNameHelper.html

Here the method `isValidIdentifier` **Check if supplied name is a valid java package name portion or class identifier.*

Comment: Do not suggest third party libraries please. I'll add that to original question as well.

Comment: is there any issue using 3rd party libraries ? why do we need to re-invent a wheel ?

Comment: You can also check 3rd party library licence and if it's okay, then just copy and use theire code.

Answer (score 0):

The bullet-proof solution made easy with regular expressions:

```
String NAME = "\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*";
String DOT = "\\.";
String DOTTED_NAME = NAME + "(?:" + DOT + NAME + ")*";
Pattern DOTTED_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(DOTTED_NAME);

boolean isJavaName(String name) {
    Matcher matcher = DOTTED_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(name);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```